# How session.get() initializes the object even if we dont provide setter method in the entity

Tags: hibernate

How session.get() initializes the object from database, even if we dont provide setter method in the entity.

In my UserDetails class I have not used setter method but how hibernate is initializing the userName member variable.

Main class:

```
package org.hibernatetest.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.demo.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    UserDetails user=(UserDetails)session.get(UserDetails.class,1);
    System.out.println(user.getUserName());

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
```

}

UserDetails Class:

```
package org.hibernate.demo;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int userId;
private String userName;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The standard is the way the ID is mapped. So when you placed your `@Id` annotation on a FIELD, all access will happen through the FIELD(Persistence provider uses [Reflection](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reflection-in-java/)), when ID is mapped on the getter/setter methods, all FIELD of class will use the getter/setter methods.

In your application,You annotated your FIELD as below,So your entity has FIELD-based access,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int userId;
```

So the persistence provider run-time accesses FIELD directly using [The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).
Thus you are not required in any way to provide a setter or getter.

If you annotate getter method with `@Id` annotation then the Persistence provider will access property through the getter (Accessor) and setter (Mutator) methods and not use reflection. In that case, both a getter and a setter should be present.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mihir :)